# How can I save a PDF-document for each distinct name found in a list?

Tags: c#, list, foreach, ienumerable, pdfsharp

Using [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/), I would like to **create one PDF-document for each distinct value in the property of the `List` I am looping through**.

Grouping my collection, and creating a `List`:

```
var listName = collectionName
    .GroupBy(p => new { p.propertyName })
    .ToList();
```

Trying to execute my PDFsharp-code for every `propertyName` in `listName`:

```
foreach (var trip in paidTrip) {
    // Getting just the name string from the specific propertyName key
    string[] remove = { "{", "}", "propertyName", "=" };
    string pnString = trip.Key.ToString();
    foreach (string item in remove) {
        pnString = pnString.Replace(item, string.Empty);
}
```

Right here is where I believe I drop the ball; how can I bring each name with me to their distinct PDF-document? I am missing that connection.
So, underneath this, I start creating my PDF-document(s):

```
    // Continued
    System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
    PdfDocument doc = new();
    PdfPage page = doc.AddPage();
    XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
    // Adding fonts and brushes...
    
    // Adding some text, to check If I am able to grab the names of propertyName (which I am - but jut the first, once)...
    gfx.DrawString(pnString, new XFont("Arial", 40, XFontStyle.Bold), myGreen, new XPoint(5, 250));

    // And then, saving the PDF-document
    doc.Save("C:\My\File\Path\Test.pdf");
```

But as I said, this just saves one PDF for the first name found.
I believe it is trying to save one file per name found, but it can't, because the file has already been created with the file name specified.

So my question is: **how can I make sure that each name found in the foreach loop is brought with me to when I create the PDFs, and save one PDF-document for each of them?**

Comment: How do you expect there to be n Files, when you save to the same filename? You need to execute the third snippet for each iteration in the second, and make sure the output files have distinct names.

Comment: You're grouping by the `propertyName` when creating your list, iterating through it and then using the `trip.Key` to write the string/text and then as `Fildor` says, saving it to the same filename of `Test.pdf`

Inside of your foreach loop, you should create a distinct name for the pdf, e.g: `$"{pnString}.pdf"` then when it iterates through the list, it will create a new PDF file for each of the grouped `propertyName` in the list.

Comment: @ConnorTJ Thanks alot! The code is in the `foreach`, just a bit hard to understand from the way I structured my post. So, adding `{pnString}` to the file path did the trick. Great!
Add your comment as solution, and I'll accept it.

Comment: @OleM I have added it as an Answer, glad it helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the end when saving your file, you need to change the filename to be the key from your list like so:

```
// And then, saving the PDF-document
doc.Save($"C:\My\File\Path\{pnString}.pdf");
```

This will save an individual file for each of the different `propertyName` Keys you performed the `GroupBy` on previously.

Answer (score 2):

Put your code inside foreach loop :) PPAPed:

```
 foreach (var trip in paidTrip) {
        // Getting just the name string from the specific propertyName key
        string[] remove = { "{", "}", "propertyName", "=" };
        string pnString = trip.Key.ToString();
        foreach (string item in remove) {
            pnString = pnString.Replace(item, string.Empty);
        }

        // Continued 
        // [..] the rest of the code here
  }
```

Comment: Also, the files need different names ...

Comment: Thanks @smiech! My code is in the `foreach`, just a bit confusing the way I set up my question.